# How to use a For Loop to add the elements at the end of the Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have an array like so:

```
const r1 = 1.5;
const r4 = 2.7;
const r5 = 5.8;
const r6 = [r1, r4, r5];
document.write(r6);
```

And I need to add the following elements at the end of the array `r6`: `1` `2` `3` `4` `5` `6` `7` `8` `9` `10` .... up to `101` by using For Loop and print this out by using `document.write();`.

Does anyone know how could I do that?

Comment: what does the code have to do with a for loop?

Comment: `Array.push()` does the same thing.

Comment: In the future, I'd recommend doing some searching and making an attempt for yourself before asking others to solve the problem for you.

Comment: @epascarello Code has printed the all elements of the array!

Comment: @Arvind I have tried the 'Array.push()' but my output was a bit different from what it should be! But, now I guess with the help of acdcjunior I know I how to do that in a proper way!

Comment: @kingdaro Yes, your right. I did try but I just didn't post my attempts because I didn't want to create a more confusion! As the newbie to JavaScript, I'm still learning and sometimes what the experienced folks recommend from Stackoverflow I couldn't find anywhere. Big Thank you to all of you guys for your time and help!!

Answer (score 2):

The method you are looking for is [`.push(newElement)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). This method appends values to the end of a given array (in your case `r6`).

You can use it within a [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop like below.

```js
const r1 = 1.5;
const r4 = 2.7;
const r5 = 5.8;
const r6 = [r1, r4, r5];

// for iterates from 1 to 101
for (var i = 1; i <= 101; i++) {
  r6.push(i); // adds the i element at the end of the r6 array
}

document.write(r6);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! You help me a lot, Not just with posting the way it could be accomplished but for your time and attempt to help me out with that. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

here, if you want to add 1-101 in existing `r6` array

```
  for (let i = 1; i <= 101; i++) {
    r6.push(i);
  }
```